# Prolog multiple unifications to one variable

Tags: prolog, prolog-findall

I need to unify all terms in database to one variable.

For given code:

```
man('a').
man('b').

main :-
        prompt(_, ''),
        man(X),
        write(X),
        nl,
        halt.
```

I get output:

```
a
```

I need to get something like:

```
['a','b']
```

Is it possible? I know about retract/1, which deletes the term from database, I could iterate trough all theese facts and retract them from database one by one, but that seems to be like shoting in the leg. Any given advice is apreciated.

Comment: You can use `findall/3` to retrieve a list of results, so `findall(X, man(X), L)` will generate a list `L = ['a', 'b']`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a collection of facts such as:

```
man(a).
man(b).
```

As was stated in the comments, you can find all the solutions with `findall`:

```
| ?- findall(X, man(X), Solutions).
Solutions = [a, b]
```

You can also modify your original program to use a failure-driven loop. `fail` in Prolog does just that: it fails, and so it causes Prolog to backtrack. Once `man(X)` fails to find more solutions, then the first clause of `main` will finally fail Prolog to the second clause which will simply succeed with no further action:

```
main :-
    man(X),
    write(X),
    nl,
    fail.
main.
```

Now if you query `main` you get:

```
| ?- main.
a
b

yes
| ?-
```

In the context of a broader program, `findall/3` may be preferred since it captures the solutions for you, whereas the above merely "prints" them out without collecting them. Although, there are times when that's all that is desired.